# What is a Witten diagram?

Tags: terminology, feynman-diagrams, ads-cft, holographic-principle

Recently I heard the terminology of [Witten diagram](http://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=Witten+diagram). Studying QFT, I frequently see Feynman diagrams and use them to compute scattering amplitudes, one-loop corrections and so on. In string theory courses I often compute string amplitudes with the extended string theory version of Feyman diagrams.

Can you explain to me what "Witten diagram" means? If possible one example would be helpful.

Comment: Did you try a Google search? Witten diagrams usually refer to diagrams indicating scattering processes in AdS/CFT. See for example, http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/physics/8-821-string-theory-fall-2008/lecture-notes/lecture16.pdf and references therein.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Witten diagram is a diagramatic method to calculate the CFT correlation functions using the bulk information. Say you have a $\lambda \phi^3 $ interaction in the bulk, you can obtain the $\langle \mathcal O (\mathbf k_1) \mathcal O (\mathbf k_2) \mathcal O (\mathbf k_3)  \rangle$ CFT correlation function by doing a integration in the bulk AdS spacetime.